# Security group in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I have configured sugarCRM 6.5 community edition and trying to create groups in which i have to add users.So this group members can't access data of other group.Is this is possible to do it in community edition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use SuiteCRM, instead of SugarCRM Community edition. It has SecuritySuite free version integratedwhich can help to solve your group managmeent problems

Or you can download trial of module **SecuritySuite** [here](https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/securitysuite)

Comment: Thanks for information may i have to look other CRM also.

Comment: Well... it is the same CRM ( SugarCRM Community 6.5 ) but under different sauce - it is built using only Open-Source components of SugarCRM 6.5

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible for sure.

It seems, you have already created Team (Group) and Users module, further you need,

1. Role module to bind with your Team module, so to define access for a record, using SugarCRM UI.
2. List View query modification, for users to see records for their ownership/belonging Team (Group).
3. And finally ACL modification of a record, for its access.

Quite achievable with a step by step approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in SugarCRM 6.5 community edition.

It seems, you have already created Group and assigned users to this group, further you need,

1. Edit Group from Role Management
2. Set "Owner" value in particular module like Leads
3. Save
4. Re-login in SuagrCRM. you can see only own leads